# Does not using the httpClient.BaseAddress on some calls causes a new client creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.1, httpclientfactory

I'm using the `.net core 2.1` `HttpFactory` and I set a `BaseAddress` in the startup when calling `services.AddHttpClient`.

Almost all my calls use the `BaseAddress`, but some need to call other URLs, so for those, I directly pass the full URL.

Does this dispose of my `httpClient` and create a new one? Should I instead have 2 different client types and register both with their respective `BaseAddress` in the startup (can I even do that with the `HttpFactory`?)?

I'm asking the question, as my integration tests have problems with calls using a "timeout style" cancellation token.

PS: Not using the `BaseAddress` would be a pain, as the URLs depend on the environment.

---

Update: I tested registering named clients instead. One for the main cases and another one with a different `BaseAddress`. It seems to have helped my integration tests, as now they rarely timeout (and when they do, I think it may be related to another issue).

This adds to my original question, as it seems to affect the performance. So again, could it be possible that using the same `Client` for calls using either the `BaseAddress` or a full address would prompt disposals/recreations of the `Client` from the `HttpFactory`?

Comment: how did you determine it creates new instance?

Comment: I did not determine that. I'm wondering, as it seems to affect performance on my integration tests. I just updated my original post with more information.